Minimum Regular Expression for Strings not Containing Substring?
Given an alphabet $\Sigma$ and a fixed nonempty string $w$, consider the problem of finding a minimum regular expression $R(\Sigma, w)$ for all strings in $\Sigma^\star$ that do not contain $w$ as a substring.
Clearly such a regular expression exists, but I'm interested in the size of $R(\Sigma, w)$; I'll interpret the size here as number of operations + number of single characters + parentheses.
The only operations are union, concat, and star (i.e., no complement/intersection, which would make the problem more-or-less trivial).
I'm interested in exact results if known, and upper bounds/asymptotics if not, and partial results for different alphabet sizes if als known.
One bound is to start with a regex for all strings that do contain $w$, and then perform the usual regex $\to$ minimum-size DFA $\to$ complemented DFA $\to$ regex conversions.
Of course this bound can be exponential in $|\Sigma|, |w|$.
One partial result: if $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$ and $w$ is of the form $axa$ for some non-empty string $x$ of $b$'s, then one can make $R(\Sigma, w)$ as follows: $b^\star (a(\epsilon | b | \ldots | b^{|x|-1} | b^{|x|+1}b^\star))^\star a^\star$, which is of size $O(|w|^2)$.

I assume that your notion of  regular expression does not  contain complement
and intersection.

@MartinBerger correct.

It looks like there's a typo in your last example. You’ve opened two parentheses but only closed one, which makes it unclear how the star is meant to apply.

@MojtabaValizadeh thanks! Fixed.

I have no quantitative bounds, but plain regular expressions have
no succinct way of expressing what is not in their language. They
only talk about what is in the language. So I expect that the bounds
will be big. You can run some experiments with our tool
https://github.com/MojtabaValizadeh/paresy by taking a string $w$ and crafting suitable $(P, N)$ sets. Then the tool will give you a guaranteed minimal expression (or run OOM). That could give you hints for theorems to prove.
